# Response code 4** in Jmeter

Tags: testing, web-applications, jmeter, fiddler, load-testing

I am trying to load-test a web application using JMeter. I used proxy and then run the test. I am able to login into the application, but for some pages it is giving response code 4** in JMeter.

After some homework I found that the request I am sending through the browser and Jmeter might be different, so to check the same I am using fiddler. Is this the correct approach to find the root cause of the problem? What all things/attributes I should compare in fiddler and Jmeter for such requests?

Any help is appreciated. If you want, I can provide more information.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: for browser and Jmeter both refer url is same and cookie/login both contains same key, but from browser request cookie is expanding(showing + sign ) where as from Jmeter cookie/login is in single line . do i need to check something else ?

Comment: I found one diffrence in fidler under *header* in correct request *Entity* is coming ,while in Jmeter request the *Entity* is missing.(Entity contains : Content-type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8) does it matters, if yes then how to add it in Jmeter request?do i need to check something else ?

Comment: What kind of authorization you are using? Query parameters? Windows NTLM authentication?
Also it would be easier to answer if you can attach the screenshots of your requests and responses in both the cases. (Success & failure)

Answer (score 0):

Abhijeet,
Edit the jmeter.properties file which is located in the bin directory.
Un-comment the proxy.content_type_include=text/html|text/plain|text/xml
Save the file and restart Jmeter.
Try recording and see if this makes a difference.